# kubevirt: create VM with 20 G under "/"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, virtual-machine, kubectl

I'm using KubeVirt, I'd like to build a Ubuntu virtual machine inside Kubernetes. When I make it with my yaml file, there isn't enough space in the "/".

How can I create a Virtual Machine (VM) that requires a minimum of 20 GB of disk space under the "/"? 
my used yaml code is :

```
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachineInstance
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-vmi
  labels:
    vmi : ubuntu-vmi
spec:
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  domain:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 2
        memory: 8Gi #9216Mi
        
    devices:
      disks:
      - name: containerdisk
        disk:
          bus: virtio
      - disk:
          bus: virtio
        name: cloudinitdisk
  volumes:
  - name: containerdisk
    containerDisk:
      image: tedezed/ubuntu-container-disk:22.0
  - name: cloudinitdisk
    cloudInitNoCloud:
      userData: |-
        #cloud-config
        password: ubuntu
        chpasswd: { expire: False }
        ssh_authorized_keys:
        - ssh-rsa ...
        package_update: true
        package_upgrade: true
        packages: 
        - qemu-guest-agent
        runcmd:
        - [ systemctl, start, qemu-guest-agent ]
```

thank you for help!